# How to save multiple JSON strings in a single file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following multiple JSON strings in a file:

```
{
  "col1": "e1",
  "col2": "e5"
}
{
  "col1": "a1",
  "col2": "a4",
  "col3": "e8"
}
```

This is how I read this file:

```
import json
data = []
for line in open('test.json', 'r', encoding='cp850'):
   data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Is there any way to say this file back in the following format (i.e. all JSON strings would be wrapped inside `[..]` and there should be commas separating them):

```
[
    {
      "col1": "e1",
      "col2": "e5"
    },
    {
      "col1": "a1",
      "col2": "a4",
      "col3": "e8"
    }
]
```

For those who need some examples as a proof of whatever, I tried this:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

It does not write the content of `data` into JSON file.

And a dirty solution that neither works:

```
data = ""
with open('test.json', 'r', encoding='cp850') as myfile:
    data = str(json.loads(line)) + "," + data

data = data[:len(data)-1] + "]" + data[len(data):]
data = "[" + data

with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: you have all in `data`  so use it with `json.dumps(data)` and save it

Comment: @hek2mgl I missed the detail on the jsonline, thought it was a straight json file.  Still, I felt the attempt was there, just not the greatest attempt.  FWIW, I'm neutral on the question.

Comment: Since it's not clear what the actual structure of your raw file is, here's a very ghetto way of doing it, just for fun :) `with open('test.json', 'r', encoding='cp850') as file: data = eval('[{d}]'.format(d=file.read().replace('}','},')))`.  Just to be clear, *I would not recommend this at all*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to have multiple JSONs per file without some kind of delimiter.

I recommend newline delimited (meaning, each JSON object is confined to 1 line in the file):

```
{"name": "json1"}
{"name": "json2"}
{"name": "json3"}
```

Then you can simply iterate the file and do something like this:

```
objs = []
with open("jsons.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        objs.append(json.loads(line))

with open("jsons.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(obj, f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = \
"""{
  "col1": "e1",
  "col2": "e5"
}
{
  "col1": "a1",
  "col2": "a4",
  "col3": "e8"
}
"""

new_json = []
bracket_lvl = 0
curr_json = ''
for c in data:
    curr_json += c

    if c in (' ', '\t', '\n'):
        continue

    if c == '{':
        bracket_lvl += 1
    if c == '}':
        bracket_lvl -= 1

    if bracket_lvl == 0:
        new_json.append(curr_json)
        curr_json = ''

output = "[\n" + ','.join(new_json) + "\n]"

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[
{
  "col1": "e1",
  "col2": "e5"
},
{
  "col1": "a1",
  "col2": "a4",
  "col3": "e8"
}
]
```

**Edit:**

Please note, this only works if the json strings are surrounded by curly braces - if you need code to handle square braces, I'll need to slightly edit this...

**Edit 2:**

If you want to save it to a file, use this at the bottom of the program:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```